# Maximum of two symbolic expressions in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, max

If I have two symbolic expressions and the algebra can tell which one is the largest, how can I get Mathematica to find that out? Example:

```
A = s1/z1 + s2/z2 + Sqrt[(s1/z1 + s2/z2)^2 + 4 (z1^2 z2^2 - s1 s2)/(z1 z2)];
B = s1/z1 + s2/z2 - Sqrt[(s1/z1 + s2/z2)^2 + 4 (z1^2 z2^2 - s1 s2)/(z1 z2)];
Assuming[s1 > 0 && s2 > 0 && z1 > 0 && z2 > 0, Max[A, B]]
```

This gives

```
Max[s1/z1 + s2/z2 - Sqrt[(s1/z1 + s2/z2)^2 + (4 (-s1 s2 + z1^2 z2^2))/(z1 z2)], 
 s1/z1 + s2/z2 + Sqrt[(s1/z1 + s2/z2)^2 + (4 (-s1 s2 + z1^2 z2^2))/(z1 z2)]]
```

which not much of use.
However, one can see that it's always A < B, because A is a difference between two positive numbers, while B is the sum. I'd like Mathematica to tell me that the Max is always B. Can it be done?

Comment: try `Simplify[Reduce[A>B]]` with assumptions. is that sqrt guaranteed real by the assumptions?

Comment: Good point, how do I tell Mathematica that the Sqrt of a real non negative number is a (real) non negative number? (the argument of Sqrt can be easily shown to be always non negative)

Comment: it should come out if your assumptions are sufficient.  However be aware only certain functions utilize/respect assumptions.  I suspect `Max` does not.  `Reduce` should give a conditional expression which `Simplify` might clean up using your assumptions. (I did not test..).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had a chance to check ..

```
 Assuming[ {z1 > 0, z2 > 0, s1 > 0, s2 > 0} , Simplify[Reduce[A > B]]]
```

-> True

note by removing the `Simplify` and looking at the conditional expression produced by `Reduce` you can see how to relax the assumptions a bit:

```
 Assuming[ {z1 > 0, z2 > 0, Element[{s1, s2}, Reals]} , Simplify[Reduce[A > B]]]
```

-> True

Note also  `Reduce[A < B]` returns `False` with no assumptions. That expression can not be true even with complex expressions.

I suppose if you want to implement something like `Max` you could do this:

```
 Assuming[ {z1 > 0, z2 > 0, s1 > 0, s2 > 0} ,
    Which[ Simplify[Reduce[A > B]] , A ,
           Simplify[Reduce[B > A ]] , B , 
              True , Indeterminate ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by agentp can be also made iterative, so one can generalize this to more than two expressions:

```
v = {A, B};
max = B;
Assuming[{z1 > 0, z2 > 0, s1 > 0, s2 > 0},
     For[i = 1, i <= 2, i++,
      If[Simplify[Reduce[v[[i]] > max]], max = v[[i]]]
      ]
]
Print[max];
```

-> s1/z1+s2/z2+Sqrt[(s1/z1+s2/z2)^2+(4 (-s1 s2+z1^2 z2^2))/(z1 z2)]